# Other paradigms beyond MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

MapReduce is the most popular paradigm to process files in a distributed system. However the YARN architecture make possible the programer build applications using others paradigm.
Of course some paradigms are better than others for some applications.

For example:

I'm using MapReduce to process a video file but this _________ paradigm is better.

I'm using MapReduce to process sql query files but this ________ paradigm is better.

I want to know the best way to choose a paradigm more efficient according the problem.

I hope someone can understand the question.

Comment: map reduce is for distributing processing of large amounts of data. there are no better choices if you process terabytes of data distributed over a big number of nodes.

Comment: Hive runs SQL using MapReduce... As for video files, that depends what you want to do with them